# Using javascriptExecutor to find a WebElement

Tags: java, jquery, selenium

The title says all, I need a way to select a WebElement.

I am using Firefox Quantum (latest beta version).

This is what I tried.

```
String ccNumberSelector = "'#card_details > div > input'";
                            Object ccNumberField = js.executeScript("return $(" + ccNumberSelector + ").eq(0);");
                            ((WebElement) ccNumberField).sendKeys("some key sequence");
```

All that this does is 'freeze' (not really freeze, it just blocks the whole webpage, like you can't interact with it anymore).

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I CANNOT use any other selector than this (id's and everything else are random).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`js.executeScript("return document.querySelector(" + ccNumberSelector + ");`

Warning: The argument for `querySelector` must be a CSS Selector, not XPath.